# Instantiating an abstract class Scala? Possible at all?

Tags: scala, abstract-class

For an abstract class I'm trying to define some of its methods so I don't have to for each subclass. One of the methods I'm trying to do this with needs to return an instance of this class. Is there any way to do this, as I can't instantiate the class because it's abstract?

Here's a snippet of the code example, but there isn't any actual code, I'm just showing it to make my question clearer. What / would do is create a new ListHolder that was the original ListHolder plus the parameter ListHolder with all the elements of both. NOT in a list, but a ListHolder.

```
abstract class ListHolder {
    def /(other: ListHolder) : ListHolder = ???
}
```

Can I implement the `/` method at the abstract level, considering it has to return a `ListHolder`?

Comment: You don't really want to instantiate the abstract class. You want to create instances of the respective child classes in each one. I think your title is misleading.

Comment: I need to return a value though if I want to implement this function in the superclass, and I need a value to actually exist to do this, and am wondering if it's possible and I don't know how you would without instantiating an abstract class.

Comment: Well, it would need to be something like `return new (this.constructor)` - refering to the respective child constructor, not your abstract class. There are no instances of your abstract class, so it would never refer to the (uninstantiatable) abstract constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You sort of instantiate an abstract class by instantiating an anonymous subclass:

```
new ListHolder {}
```

So maybe?:

```
abstract class ListHolder {
  def /(other: ListHolder) : ListHolder = new ListHolder {}
}

class SomeListHolder extends ListHolder

new SomeListHolder / new SomeListHolder
// res0: ListHolder = ListHolder$$anon$1@520a06c6
```

Or you can just return a particular pre-chosen subtype:

```
abstract class ListHolder {
  def /(other: ListHolder) : ListHolder = new SomeListHolder
}

new SomeListHolder / new SomeListHolder
// res0: ListHolder = SomeListHolder@483edb6b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare method return types in terms of the implementing class using `this.type`:

```
trait AbstractFuncs {
  def someFunc: this.type = {
    // do something...
    this
  }
}

case class A(val i: Int) extends AbstractFuncs
case class B(val j: Double) extends AbstractFuncs 

val a1 = A(10)
val b1 = B(15.13)

val a11: A = a1.someFunc
val b11: B = b1.someFunc
```

Answer (score 0):

What about having `def abstract ListHolder makeNew(...)` or whatever in `ListHolder`? Then you would just redefine that part in subtype and keep the rest of the implementation of `/` in the ListHolder.

It is difficult to be more precise without any idea of what `/` does.

There might also be question about whether you allow / with two arguments of different types, and whether you want to guarantee that the return type is the same as the actual type of the operands (which would require a type parameter or an abstract type member)